# Drawing on the canvas with a "pencil"

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I made a [script](http://jsfiddle.net/gtr053/mz6hK/6/) that draws a series of lines on a canvas that makes it look like a sketch. There are two issues with the script. One, why is the y value twice as much as it should be? And two, why is the line several pixels wide and faded out?

I've tried it in both Google Chrome and Firefox and I get the same incorrect results. I realize that I can divide the y value by two to fix the first problem but that part of my question is why do I need to do that. I shouldn't have to.

Comment: lineWidth might fix the width of the line issue ; the fadind out is probably due to anti aliasing capabilities of canvas. Regarding the y problem, I don't get it : do you have some code we could check ?

Comment: I've seen your code : you need to give a width and a height to your canvas !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have two issues:

1. You need to be more careful in how you calculate the offset of where to draw. I have some code below that demonstrates how to handle this properly.
2. You aren't setting the width and height on the `<canvas>` element itself, which means it will scale your lines in funny ways depending how what you've set in your css.

**An Example**

I built a simple collaborative drawing app using `<canvas>` and socket.io that lets you draw to the screen like a pencil. You can check it out here:

http://xjamundx.no.de/

The source is also on github if that might help:

- https://github.com/xjamundx/CollabPaintJS/ (main repo)
- https://github.com/xjamundx/CollabPaintJS/blob/master/public/collabpaint.js (canvas drawing code)

In particular I do something like this to figure out where to draw things:

```
x = e.clientX + window.scrollX
y = e.clientY + window.scrollY
x -= $game.offsetLeft
y -= $game.offsetTop
```

Comment: Setting the width and height in the HTML instead of the CSS fixed both problems! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Give a width and a height to your canvas; always !
http://jsfiddle.net/mz6hK/7/

fixed

Comment: No offense, but this question already has an accepted answer that mentions what you answered. If I didn't know any better, I'd accuse of stealing somebody else's answer.

Comment: yea i've seen that, and a better one but i was checking your code while the other guy answered ; no offense